# What is an Origamic Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule I call it an Origamic Word™

| Origamic Words™ | Not Origamic Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| YAHOO | GOOGLE |
| VICTIM | MURDER |
| TWO | ONE |
| HAWK | FALCON |
| MAMMOTH | ELEPHANT |
| ITCHY | MOSQUITO |
| DIET | PIZZA |
| COKE | SPRITE |
| ADDICTIVE | HEROIN |
| WHAMMY | CHRISTMAS |

The CSV version:

```
Origamic Words™, Not Origamic Words™
YAHOO, GOOGLE
VICTIM, MURDER
TWO, ONE
HAWK, FALCON
MAMMOTH, ELEPHANT
ITCHY, MOSQUITO
DIET, PIZZA
COKE, SPRITE
ADDICTIVE, HEROIN
WHAMMY, CHRISTMAS
```

Can you tell me what the rule is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An Origamic Word™ is a word ...

> ... where all letters are axisymmetric in their capital form. These are the letters A, C, D, E, H, I, K, M, O, T, V, W, Y. The letters S, N and Z have rotational symmetry and are not allowed in Origamic Words™. Whether the symmetry axis is vertical or horizontal doesn't matter.

The are called Origamic™, because ...

> ... one half of the letter can be folded onto the other, as in origami, the Japanese paper-folding technique.

Comment: lightning fast... Hope you don't mind If I hold off the tick. Upvoted

Comment: The letters"B", "U", and "X also can be folded.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess

> an Origamic word, which is formed by letters having either horizontal or   vertical symmetry. Example: ECHO

and

> Non-origamic words do not exhibit this property in at least one of its letters.

Comment: This was posted more than two hours after M Oehm's answer and states the same rule. Before posting an answer, please check that it does actually add something new. Thanks!